# Kotlin Collections : Subtracting two nullable list give incorrect result

Tags: kotlin

Using minus function on not nullable list is correctly working...

```kotlin
val listA: List<String> = listOf("1", "2", "3")
val listB : List<String> = listOf("1", "2", "3")
assertEquals(0, listB.minus(listA).size) // Test PASSED
```

...But on nullable list it's not working with safe call operator ?. WHY ?

```kotlin
val listA: List<String>? = listOf("1", "2", "3")
val listB : List<String>? = listOf("1", "2", "3")
assertEquals(0, listB?.minus(listA)?.size) // Test FAILED
```

Comment: The output is of time Int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Kotlin "gotcha" having to do with how they implemented variance of Lists and overloaded the `minus` function. You are actually calling two different overloads of the `minus` function.

In your first example, you are calling the overload with this signature:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.minus(elements: Iterable<T>): List<T>
```

It sees a `List<String>` with a parameter of an `Iterable<String>` (`listB`) so `T` is inferred as a `String` and it is able to remove the items from the List and return an empty `List<String>`.

In your second example, the above overload is not a match because `listB?.` means the receiver is a `List<String>`, but the parameter `listA` is not an `Iterable<String>`. It is an `Iterable<String>?`. So this other, less specific function overload is called instead:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.minus(element: T): List<T>
```

Since a `List<String>` is also a `List<Any?>` (due to covariance), and a `List<String>?` qualifies as an `Any?`, the function is a match using a `T` of `Any?`. And since the List instance itself isn't an item in `listB` the returned List doesn't have any fewer items than `listB` had.

When working with nullable lists, the `orEmpty()` function often comes in handy:

```
val listA: List<String>? = listOf("1", "2", "3")
val listB : List<String>? = listOf("1", "2", "3")
assertEquals("nullable", 0, listB.orEmpty().minus(listA.orEmpty()).size) // PASSES
```

`orEmpty()` is shorthand for `?: emptyList()` and it ensures you're working with a non-nullable list. It's also handy for nullable Strings.

Comment: @backwardforward, not sure what your suggested edit was trying to say, but the expressions `someNullableListRef.orEmpty()` and `someNullableListRef ?: emptyList()` are exactly equivalent and neither modifies a collection.